# Unity ScrollView not scrolling with Clamped or Elastic

Tags: unity, scrolling, user-interface

I have a ScrollView object in my project. It is set to Clamped.

Inside the ViewPort, I have Content and what I actually want to scroll, a TextViewMesh. The Content has a Content Size Fitter, with its Vertical fit set to Preferred Size.

The problem is, when I run it, and try to scroll, it does not scroll at all, in ScrollView to the current setting. If I set the ScrollView mode to Unrestricted, it scrolls to the infinity. What I am doing wrong? How can I set my ScrollView to scroll the text (which can vary in lenght)?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that Viewport has two children, *Content* and *Description*. You stated that *Content* has a `ContentSizeFitter` component. If your text is on the *Description* object, the `ContentSizeFitter` is not going to adjust its size for the text because *Description* is not a child of *Content*.

You may need to move *Description* to be a child of *Content*, and add a `VerticalLayoutGroup` component to *Content*.

Comment: Already tried that, and didn't work. Desctiption is not an object containing the text object, it IS the text object.

Comment: Then you need to make _Description_ a child of _Content_. The content size fitter on _Content_ will not work if _Description_ is not a child of _Content_. You may also need to add a `VerticalLayoutGroup` to _Content_ after moving _Description_

Comment: I fixed it. Deleted Content, and now there is only Description, with its ContentSizeFitter. I didn't need the VerticalLayoutGroup, however, probably because there is only one element. Your answer put me in the right track. Thank you!